# Data directory racks and kespace usability in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am concentrating on cassandra multiple data directory structure. I have basic need in keypspace split up between multiple directories as follows:
 1) I should be able to limit the number of kyspaces to the each directory.
2) Only one directory should be used actively for insertion. For example even if I have added multiple directories in configuration file, when ever I create keyspace and push records that should only go to the very first directory. It should not create keyspace or scatter records in other available directories.When my first directory overflows then only it should use the subsequent directories.
 Is there any option to achieve these two scenarios in cassandra latest version?..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pin keyspaces to a single data directory.  Cassandra will load balance across all defined directories.

Cassandra will follow symlinks, so you could define a single data directory, and symlink it to whatever volume you want...  but that will be the only data accessible for reads, as well.

Bottom line, this is not how Cassandra is designed to work and you would be better served figuring out how to work with the design instead of fighting it.